# how to preview uploaded image before saving it in database in image control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am allowing the user to upload the image.
as soon as user uploads the image the respective image should get displayed in image control(similar to the preview of image).
this should be done without clicking any button

```
<td align="right" valign="top" class="heading">Photo: </td>
<td>
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"/>
</td>
```

Comment: file gets uploaded successfully but i want the image to get displayed. i dnt know what to include in place of ImageUrl property of image tag

Comment: well if you got the upload to work, why not do something like: `Image1.url = UploadedFile.path; Image1.Update();`

Comment: can you please provide the complete code

Answer (score 0):

As you have been asking for complete code and i have no idea what it looks like here comes a piece of code with lots of assumptions...

```
public void UploadImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //here you upload your image to a predefined Path and save it...
    File image = FileUpload1.getFile();// don't know how to handle it, haven't used it b4
    image.Save(path); //path is your savepath, even if its temporary
    Image1.ImageUrl = path.ToUrl();
    //alternatively do the following:
    Image1.ImageUrl = FileInfo(image).getFullPath();

    //in general you need to update controls before they show what they got so:
    Image1.Update(); / Image1.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: UploadImage function will get invoked onclick of button but what i want is as soon as user clicks the choosefile button to browse the image and once he selects the image immediately that image should get displayed in image control. i mean preview of the uploaded image before saving it .

Comment: well you have to have it saved somewhere to display it to the user. so what you want is simply impossible

Answer (score 0):

I recently had same requirement as you ... I used AjaxFileUploader instead of normal FileUpload control .. and a Image Handler .. This helped me in achiecving it..

[Preview Image before uploading](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/40858-Preview-Image-before-uploading-using.aspx)